# What's the diference between "make yourself known" vs "to introduce oneself"

Tags: word-choice

When can I replace "to introduce oneself" with "make oneself known"?
For example, do these sentences make sense if instead of having "make yourself known" I had "introduce your self"?

> 1 Just go to the hotel reception and make yourself known (to the receptionist).

> 2 The candidate made herself known to voters through an aggressive ad campaign.

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Comment: They are just two different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: I think the first example is a bit different. "Make yourself known" implies the person already knows something about you, but needs to put your face to that name before she can send you to the right place/call somebody down to meet you/upgrade your room because you're friends with the boss. Introducing yourself would be from a place of her not knowing who you are at all. For the second, I think they're interchangeable.

Comment: Introductions are usually more personal. If someone told me to "make myself known to the receptionist" that implies (rather strongly) that the speaker views her as a non-personal helper unit. However, if someone said, "Go introduce yourself to Katie, the receptionist," that would imply that Katie and I are on the same level and there is going to be some sort of ongoing (no matter how casual) relationship.

Answer (score 1):

They mean almost the same thing but there is perhaps a slight difference. If you introduce yourself you would go up to the other person and say

> Hello, my name is Cool Guy

and offer them your hand if handshaking is a custom in your society. It is also possible to introduce someone to someone else, "Hello John, may I introduce Cool Guy" and even introduce them to an audience as @KateBunting noted in a comment.

If you make yourself known then you approach them and let them know you are there which may involve the same formula but does not have to.

So in your first example of the receptionist either wording would work but in the second example the candidate made herself known through advertisements, she did not approach each elector formally so I would have a preference for your version. But it is a very fine distinction and either version would be acceptable.

Comment: But a person can be introduced to many people at one time; for example, a  visiting speaker to their audience.

Comment: Yes @KateBunting I realised it was too strong and have toned it down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**make yourself known to someone** is used to  mean **identify yourself to someone for a purpose.**

- *make yourself known to the receptionist* so she can see we are together.
- *make yourself known to the host of the party* so she sees you are not crashing it.
- *make yourself known to the police* so they don't come looking for you later.

It is not the same as introduce yourself to the sense of meeting a person, persons or even a crowd for the first time.

Comment: I think "make yourself known" can indicate making others aware of your presence without identifying yourself (by name or otherwise) - e.g. if you're waiting for service at a counter but there is nobody there so you shout or signal to someone elsewhere in the building.